# How to copy a file without using scp inside an ssh session?

Tags: linux, unix, ssh, scp

I have logged on to a system with ssh and there is no scp present on both the systems. How to copy a file without using the scp program.

Comment: Is netcat (nc) present on both systems? If it is, use your ssh session to tunnel a TCP port and use nc on that port.

Comment: Do you have `rsync`?

Comment: you can also do this: `ssh user@remotehost cat /path/to/remote/file > /path/to/local/file`

Comment: @n.m. quotes required (for me, ubuntu server)

Comment: @n.m. Doesn't work for me - file is corrupted (I guess the login message breaks it).

Answer (score 145, accepted):

To send a file:

```sh
cat file | ssh ajw@dogmatix "cat > remote"
```

Or:

```sh
ssh ajw@dogmatix "cat > remote" < file
```

To receive a file:

```sh
ssh ajw@dogmatix "cat remote" > copy
```

Comment: @ggg that's not true at all. `cd /tmp; cat /bin/bash > test; chmod a+x test; diff test /bin/bash; ./test` all works fine. There's nothing inherently "magic" about binary files. Both files in my example compared identical and have the same checksum. It's true that copy and pasting from a terminal window won't work because of things like control sequences and unprintable characters, but using pipes like this these never go near a terminal.

Comment: @Flexo I need something like this, the only exception is, I need to pipe in all jpg from a folder. How could iterate through /storage/sdcard1/*jpg and `>` to files with the same name ?

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza you'll need to add `tar` into the mix. `tar cvf - /path/*.jpg | ssh foo@bar.com "tar xvf -"` or something similar ought to work.

Comment: One implication of what ggg and Flexo say above is that you can't use the "-t" option to ssh.

Comment: Why do you use cat?

Comment: @pyrulez - on the local end it's habbit - I normally use a pipe from some more complex process and don't just transfer files. On the remote end there needs to be a process of some sort spawned, cat is a good choice.

Comment: This is brilliant, and was necessary on the tiny embedded device I was using that didn't have scp.

Comment: Neat - this even works to copy from windows to linux if you use "type" instead of cat on the windows end (using windows 10's built in beta ssh client).    (text files, haven't tried binary)

Comment: Nice! You can also use pv instead of the first cat so you get a progressbar, eg `pv file | ssh ajw@dogmatix "cat > remote"`

Comment: WOW! This make my live so much easier on embedded stuff

Comment: google queries "copy file if scp not found", "copy file if no scp", "sh: scp: not found" should go here

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
cat myfile.txt | ssh me@otherhost 'cat - > myfile.txt'
```

Comment: no need for that many cat calls at all

Comment: What is that symbol, "-", near cat for?

Comment: @RenanWillianPrado It tells `cat` specifically to read from stdin. Mostly useful to concatenate stdin after another file.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `xxd` and some ugly quoting to copy over multiple files as well as run commands on them and execute them:

```sh
ssh -t foo@bar.com "
echo $'"$(cat somefile | xxd -ps)"' | xxd -ps -r > "'somefile'"
chmod +x somefile
echo $'"$(cat someotherfile | xxd -ps)"' | xxd -ps -r > "'someotherfile'"
chmod +x someotherfile
./somefile
./someotherfile
"
```

Comment: ah, my answer is clearly too l33t

Answer (score -2):

Besides piping the file to a remote `cat`, you may also be able to use some SFTP client to transfer the files.

Comment: +1 but it should be noted that the OP is attempting to avoid scp because it does not exist on the systems. Given this constraint it's also probable that an FTP server needs to exist on the receiving end which makes the copying process dependent on software other than what is usually there by default.

Answer (score -2):

`python3 -m http.server` in the same directory with desired file - after that you can `curl` or `wget` or download a file with your browser. Note that with that running command all your files from current directory will be publicly available, until you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.