# Process running in SSH-allocated TTY not terminating once stdin is consumed

Tags: linux, ssh, unix, tty

I can [perform file-transfer via SSH](https://superuser.com/questions/291423/how-to-copy-a-file-without-using-scp-inside-an-ssh-session)<sup>*</sup> like this:

```
ssh -T ${HOST} eval "cat > remote.txt" < local.txt
```

However, if I instead allocate a TTY, it hangs until I press Ctrl+C:

```
ssh -tt ${HOST} eval "cat > remote.txt" < local.txt
```

**Question: Why is this?  Is there a workaround?**

The best I can figure out is that the local EOF is not being propagated to the remote process.

<sub>*Platform details: OpenSSH_5.3p1, CentOS 6.7 x86_64*</sub>

---

<sub>* In my real use-case, I want to use this approach to transfer files directly to a remote sudo user; I can't use SCP because I can't SSH as the sudo user.  The sudoers file in my target environment has `requiretty` set, hence the need for a TTY.</sub>

Comment: why the `eval`? It is not needed, isn't it?

Comment: @Jakuje: `echo "hello" | ssh -T ${HOST} "cat > foo.txt"` leads to `cat: >: No such file or directory`.  And you can't remove the quotes, because then that redirection occurs locally!

Comment: @Jakuje: On further inspection, that appears to be a difference in SSH clients (the above issue is observed with OpenSSH 6.2 on OSX, but not 5.3 on Linux).

Comment: Are you trying on the same server? This might be problem with different shells on server. But, yes, using `exec` makes sure it works almost everywhere. The tty allocation is evergreen problem since 2001, aka [bug #52 in openssh](https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=52), still not completely solved.

Comment: @Jakuje - It's not immediately obvious that this is the same issue.  The description there involves the child process (`sleep`) not receiving a `SIGHUP` at the "correct" time; in my case the child `cat` process is never terminating, presumably because its stdin is never exhausted.

Answer (score 0):

#### Some theory

> The best I can figure out is that the local EOF is not being propagated to the remote process.

Basically yes, you can say that. In *nix EOF is not a character, it's a condition. When a program reading a file uses `read()` and there is nothing more to read, it gets 0 bytes and then it knows it got to the end of the file.

Reading from a terminal is somewhat different. Your `ssh -tt` allocates a terminal on the remote side and your remote `cat` reads from this terminal. The terminal is in the `icanon` mode. In this mode the terminal driver buffers data (normally this allows basic edits, like with <kbd>Backspace</kbd>), it sends data upon <kbd>Enter</kbd>. In your case it will interpret [any `\r` and any `\n` character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representation) coming from `local.txt` as <kbd>Enter</kbd>. When there is nothing more to read, there's also no <kbd>Enter</kbd>, so the terminal driver sends nothing and `read()` of your `cat` keeps waiting. It makes sense because normally it's a user typing at the terminal; assuming EOF when the user does not type fast enough would be very wrong.

There is a way to make a terminal driver in `icanon` mode send 0 bytes. If it reads a character `\004` (ASCII EOT) then it will send everything it's currently buffering (buffering while awaiting for <kbd>Enter</kbd>). Normally you send `\004` to a terminal by typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> instead of <kbd>Enter</kbd> will make the terminal driver send the already typed line without any newline (or such) character. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> after <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> after <kbd>Enter</kbd>) will send exactly 0 bytes and *then* a tool like your `cat` will see the EOF condition and it will exit.

A basic (which does not mean "good") workaround is to send at least two `\004` characters after the content of your local file:

```
{ cat local.txt; printf '\004\004'; } | ssh -tt …
```

You can read more here:

- [Ctrl+D for ending terminal line input](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/177661/108618)
- [Why does Ctrl-D (EOF) exit the shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/110248/108618)

In case of `ssh -tt …`, catching `\004` characters is not everything the terminal driver on the remote side does. It does a lot more, both to data coming from the client and to data coming to the client (printed by the remote command). Let's investigate some possibilities, obstacles and quirks.

---

#### Some practice

Preliminary notes:

- All examples use `ssh -tt`. The assumption is you have your reasons and `-tt` is a must.
- If you want to replicate the below examples, set `remote='user@server'` with values of `user` and `server` that work for you. The point is to allow you to copy-paste my commands without tinkering.
- The examples don't use `eval` though. I don't really understand why you needed `eval` in the question. If it turns out you need `eval` to make the examples work then you'll have to tinker. Sorry. The examples work for me.
- The examples show `ssh` that works without prompting for password and works reasonably fast.
- `$`  denotes my prompt. `#` denotes a comment. A line with a command is always in the form of the prompt followed by the command. Then there's output I got (if any). Additional prompt at the end of the last line indicates the command exited; no prompt at the end of the last line indicates the command stalled. `_` indicates the position of the local caret (text cursor) after the command exited or stalled.
- We want to investigate the behavior of the remote terminal. There's also a local terminal. It does not interfere with input (our commands won't use it as input), but it may interfere with output. To put the local terminal aside, we may locally write to a regular file or pipe to (e.g.) `od -c`. I decided it would only obfuscate the examples. The existence of the local terminal does not affect the conclusions we will come to.
- I will often use descriptions of keystrokes (e.g. <kbd>Enter</kbd>) to refer to characters we send (e.g. `\n`). It will not always be totally accurate (e.g. your <kbd>Enter</kbd> probably generates `\r`, not `\n`). I think keystrokes are more readable, interpret them more as indications of what we want the remote terminal driver to do.

These are the examples:

1. Let's replicate your problem:

   ```
   $ printf 'Line1\nLine2' | ssh -tt "$remote" cat
   Line1
   Line2Line1
   _
   ```

   Why is there `Line1` twice? Because the remote terminal echoes its input. Let's do something about it.
2. Let's try to suppress remote echo:

   ```
   $ printf 'Line1\nLine2' | ssh -tt "$remote" 'stty -echo; cat'
   Line1
   Line2Line1
   _
   ```

   It didn't work. It's not obvious, but the reason is the remote terminal echoed its input before `stty -echo` reconfigured it.
3. Let's give some time for `stty -echo`:

   ```
   $ { sleep 1; printf 'Line1\nLine2'; } | ssh -tt "$remote" 'stty -echo; cat'
   Line1
   _
   ```

   Now we see `Line1` came through `cat`, but `Line2` probably didn't.

   <sup>Note `sleep 1` is already a hack. If the server was busy or the communication with the server was slow, `sleep 1` might not suffice.</sup>
4. Let's "hit" <kbd>Enter</kbd> after `Line2`:

   ```
   $ { sleep 1; printf 'Line1\nLine2\n'; } | ssh -tt "$remote" 'stty -echo; cat'
   Line1
   Line2
   _
   ```
5. Let's send <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> instead of this <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

   ```
   $ { sleep 1; printf 'Line1\nLine2\004'; } | ssh -tt "$remote" 'stty -echo; cat'
   Line1
   Line2_
   ```

   Note the caret is not in the same place as before.
6. Let's send <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> twice:

   ```
   $ { sleep 1; printf 'Line1\nLine2\004\004'; } | ssh -tt "$remote" 'stty -echo; cat'
   Line1
   Line2Connection to … closed.
   $ _
   ```

   The remote `cat` exited. The above is our basic workaround. `Connection to … closed.` (with one trailing newline character) comes from `ssh` itself and it's printed locally to its stderr, i.e. to the local terminal. It has nothing to do with the remote terminal. From now on we will suppress it with `2>/dev/null`.
7. Let's send something more:

   ```
   $ { sleep 1; printf 'Line1\nLine2\004\004 Line2 continues'; } | ssh -tt "$remote" 'stty -echo; cat' 2>/dev/null
   Line1
   Line2$ _
   ```

   The double <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> really made our `cat` see EOF, it didn't read the rest of the input.
8. There are more characters that interact with the remote terminal driver. `\010` (octal 10, decimal 8, ASCII BS) is like <kbd>Backspace</kbd>. Let's not annoy our remote `cat` by saying we like dogs:

   ```
   $ { sleep 1; printf 'I like dogs\010\010\010\010cats.\n\004'; } | ssh -tt "$remote" 'stty -echo; cat' 2>/dev/null
   I like cats.
   $ _
   ```

   Here we used a single <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> after <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This <kbd>Enter</kbd> is also the reason the final local prompt is in a separate line, not just after the dot.
9. We can send <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> (`\003`, ASCII ETX):

   ```
   $ { sleep 1; printf 'I like...\ndogs\03'; } | ssh -tt "$remote" 'stty -echo; cat' 2>/dev/null
   $ _
   ```

   Despite <kbd>Enter</kbd> in the stream (which normally would make `cat` read and print `I like...`), the output is empty. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> was caught by the remote terminal driver, the driver sent `SIGINT` and `cat` was terminated before it managed to print. Yes, `\03` in the input really causes a signal. We will see it more clearly if we manage to set a trap in the remote shell before our local `sleep 1` passes.
10. Trapping <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>:

    ```
    $ { sleep 1; printf '\03'; } | ssh -tt "$remote" 'stty -echo; trap "echo trap" INT; sleep 2' 2>/dev/null
    trap
    $ _
    ```

    As you can see, certain characters in the input cause certain modifications or actions on the remote side. For now we tested some characters that rarely occur in text files. You may think if your `local.txt` contains what people call text (letters, digits, symbols, newlines) and it's ASCII then you're safe. Well, not strictly; see the next example.
11. Windows line endings, i.e. `\r\n`.

    ```
    $ # local test, for comparison
    $ printf 'Line1\r\nLine2\r\nLine3'
    Line1
    Line2
    Line3$ _
    ```

    ```
    $ # actual remote test
    $ { sleep 1; printf 'Line1\r\nLine2\r\nLine3'; } | ssh -tt "$remote" 'stty -echo; cat' 2>/dev/null
    Line1

    Line2

    _
    ```

    Missing `Line3` and stalled command are not surprising; these empty lines may be. They appear because the terminal driver on the remote side translates every `\r` to `\n`. Instead of `\r\n` our `cat` sees `\n\n`, hence the additional lines.

    We can turn this feature off.
12. Windows line endings, without translation.

    ```
    $ { sleep 1; printf 'Line1\r\nLine2\r\nLine3'; } | ssh -tt "$remote" 'stty -echo -icrnl; cat' 2>/dev/null
    Line1
    Line2
    _
    ```

    This time `cat` got each `\r` character as `\r`. In `stty` there's also a setting that makes the terminal driver ignore `\r`. There are many settings; some affect input, some affect output. See the output of (local) `stty -a`, read `man 1 stty`. You will find (among other things) that `icanon` is not the only mode for a terminal and many features can be turned off.
13. `raw` mode.

    ```
    $ { sleep 1; printf 'Windows\r\nSIGINT\n\003Backspace\010\nEOF\004\004\nExtra\n'; } | ssh -tt "$remote" 'stty raw -echo; cat' 2>/dev/null
    Windows
    SIGINT
    Backspace
    EOF
    Extra
    _
    ```

    [`stty raw` turns many features off](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/21760/108618). In the above example neither `\r` was translated nor `\003` caused `SIGINT`, nor `\010` removed the previous character. But also `\004\004` did not work and `cat` stalled. In the local terminal output we cannot see non-printable characters, but all the characters went there and back as-is. You can confirm this by piping `ssh` to `od -c` (although due to buffering it may happen you will see a partial result).

    It's good to know `stty raw`, but of course this example suffers from the original problem: `cat` stalls and `ssh` stalls.

    `stty raw` also turns off features that affect the stream flowing from the remote to the local side. The local `ssh` prints this stream to its stdout.
14. Pulling a file. The example file is `/bin/bash` from the remote side. Note your `/bin/bash` may be a different file (in different version or whatever), so you may get different checksums.

    ```
    $ # checksum on the remote, for comparison
    $ ssh -tt "$remote" 'md5sum </bin/bash' 2>/dev/null
    4600132e6a7ae0d451566943a9e79736  -
    $ _
    ```

    ```
    $ # pulling the file and calculating checksum locally
    $ ssh -tt "$remote" 'stty raw; cat /bin/bash' 2>/dev/null | md5sum
    4600132e6a7ae0d451566943a9e79736  -
    $ _
    ```

    ```
    $ # without stty raw, for comparison
    $ ssh -tt "$remote" 'cat /bin/bash' 2>/dev/null | md5sum
    358991d6d2182cbea143297d14d98f41  -
    $ _
    ```

    The first two commands show that with `stty raw` the copy that appeared on the local side was ([almost certainly](https://superuser.com/q/1324629/432690)) identical to the remote original file. The last command shows `stty raw` is crucial, without it the local copy was different (i.e. the remote terminal driver mangled the file).

    In each case no tool read from the remote terminal, the lack of EOF condition was thus not a problem.

    It seems if the client needs `ssh -t`, using `stty raw` may be a good method for copying an arbitrary file from an SSH server to a client. I actually confirmed this also with a blob created from `/dev/urandom`, 1 GiB in size. Some observations:

    - In this case there is no relevant data that can get to the remote terminal before `stty raw` configures it. All the relevant data is from `cat` which starts after `stty raw` does its job. There is no need for local `sleep 1` or so.
    - If `stty`, `cat` or the remote shell (or anything you added to the remote command) printed to its stderr, then what it printed would corrupt the copy. The same would happen if any remote tool printed to `/dev/tty`. You can redirect stderr on the remote side, but denying access to `/dev/tty` is not that easy.

---

#### Some ideas

If you need `ssh -t`, it seems in some circumstances (no collateral printing to the terminal on the remote) you can quite reliably pull an arbitrary remote file and expect the local `ssh` to exit automatically. You just need `stty raw` on the remote side.

Putting a file in a way that makes the local `ssh` exit is problematic. You cannot do this with `stty raw`, as you need the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> mechanism to work. If you manage (and I'm not sure if it's fully possible) to configure the remote terminal driver like `stty raw` in every aspect except <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>, so capturing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> is the only thing it does to the input stream, then you should be able to put any file that doesn't contain a `\004` byte. Postpend `\004\004` and this should ultimately make `ssh` exit.

More, `stty eof` allows you to pick a byte for this purpose. The tool understands one-byte argument or the [caret notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret_notation). The latter allows you to simply use e.g. `stty eof ^A` (where `^` is literal `^` and `A` is literal `A`) and pick `\001` as the byte.

Considering the [POSIX definition of the text file](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_403), it would be best to pick `\0` (null byte) and be able to put any text file. Unfortunately [one cannot use a null byte in command-line arguments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/174017/108618). In my tests `stty eof ^@` didn't work.

Still, if you find another byte that does not appear in your file, you may succeed. In general, however, an arbitrary file may contain each possible byte at least once. [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) (or similar) encoding performed on the fly at source and decoding at destination should be a reliable solution that works with the `icanon` mode of the remote terminal driver. Example:

```
$ md5sum </bin/bash
11227b11f565de042c48654a241e9d1c  -
$ { sleep 1; base64 /bin/bash; printf '\004\004'; } | ssh -tt "$remote" 'stty -echo; base64 -d | md5sum' 2>/dev/null
11227b11f565de042c48654a241e9d1c  -
$ _
```

(The checksum is different than `4600…` calculated earlier because my local `/bin/bash` is different than my remote `/bin/bash`.)

Note if you want to save a file on the server side, you don't really need `sleep 1` (which is anyway not a perfect solution to the issue it is supposed to solve). And in fact you don't really need `stty -echo`. Allowing the remote terminal driver to echo data back (partially or in full) is only a problem in terms of wasted CPU cycles and bandwidth, but doesn't break anything (locally you can `>/dev/null`). In the above example I used `sleep 1` and `stty -echo` only because I wanted to see the output from the remote `md5sum` alone.

---

#### Different approach

I have actually solved a more general problem. See my self-answered question: [*`ssh` with separate stdin, stdout, stderr AND tty*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/653431/108618).