# How to solve corrupted downloaded files?

Tags: windows, download, download-manager, file-download

How do you solve the corrupted files after download? I have a slow internet connection that causing the downloaded file to be corrupted. The file is "zip" and about "3GB", I'm using IDM (Internet Download Manager) to download the file.

I tried searching for a solution and I found that you can convert a direct link into a torrent to avoid such a problem. But for some reason, the website that makes the magic happens is already down for some time, it's called [burnbit](http://burnbit.com/).

I wish there's an alternative download manager that makes the file secure.

I'm trying to download the file from [this](https://androidhost.ru/2CU5?pt=VTNSWE1VZFdlVWRsVm5oa2EwVmFabXRMZDBWTlp6MDlPdCtBcjBocGFYVzF3WVg1eTRzYi9xST0%3D) link.

[Here's](https://ministryofsolutions.com/2019/12/huawei-nova-2i-rne-l22-downgrade-firmware-321-asia-pacific.html) the official blog where the link is.

Comment: Some protocols are better than others; what protocol does the server let you use? (e.g. FTP, HTTP). Does the server provide redundant data for fixing corrupted downloads? (e.g. `.par2` files). Does the server provide a checksum for the file? (e.g. CRC or MD5). Maybe the file is corrupted on the server in the first place. If the checksum matches but zip is not valid, this may be the case. Are you sure the server supports resuming? Maybe it claims it does but always sends from the beginning. Can you post the actual link so we can investigate it for you? Please respond by [edit]ing the question.

Comment: Usually, it could happen when your ZIP archive is corrupted due to downloading errors or incomplete download. It seems that the third-party tool can help you, please check if methods in this article can help you: [How To Fix Corrupt ZIP File After Download Error?](https://www.yodot.com/zip-repair/corrupt-after-download-error.html)

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski - I edited my question and provided the link. Thank you!

Comment: Downloading random files from the Internet in risky. I took precautions and get the file anyway. My copy unzips well (with `7z e` on Linux). Its size is `3431764571 B`, CRC is `92da8401` and MD5 is `f776c1cf51aebd1ac31d76529ae4ccd9`. Please confirm your downloaded file differs. It may be your unzipping tool cannot handle this particular file even if it's valid; let's rule this possibility out. Calculate CRC and/or MD5 and compare. In Linux: `crc32`, `md5sum`. For Windows there are many tools that calculate checksums/hashes. I'm familiar with HashCalc from SlavaSoft. Use "data format: file".

Comment: On Windows just use Get-FileHash cmdlet in PowerShell for hashes, no third party tool required.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski - Thank you. I tried this command on CMD `CertUtil -hashfile "RNE-L22 8.0.0.321(C636) password protected.zip" MD5` and it gives me the following hash: `403bed78ef3432be8f02af7e9c5a8bfb`. It means, the file is corrupted because it didn't match with your hash, right?

Comment: I also tried using `Get-FileHash` as @XeнεiΞэnвϵς said: `Get-FileHash "RNE-L22 8.0.0.321(C636) password protected.zip" -Algorithm MD5` and the hash is also `403BED78EF3432BE8F02AF7E9C5A8BFB`.

Comment: [It means my file and your file differ.](https://superuser.com/a/1330700/432690) There is a remote possibility the site served different files (e.g. a newer version silently replaced the old one) and both are valid zips. Unlikely though; so yes, your file is corrupted.

Comment: Most Torrent downloaders, P2P file sharing software, they will verify the integrity of downloaded files, and will fix the files if they are corrupted, Google search for a way to convert the direct link to a magnetic link, this will likely solve your problem.

Comment: I have found this: https://github.com/matchai/magnetizer, I haven't tried it yet, but it is relevant, you probably need CMAKE to compile it.

Comment: @XeнεiΞэnвϵς the project has no documentation, anyway thanks! I'll try looking for an alternative.