# Unix script with a trap inside ssh

Tags: bash, ssh, terminal, unix

My plan is to write a script to debug a remote web server.

Since the debug port is blocked by the firewall, I need to forward the remote port via ssh to my local machine. This part is working fine.

The command to run the server in debug mode blocks the terminal. So when I hit CTRL C the server should be stopped. However I want the server to be started again in normal mode, when I am done with debugging. So I added a trap command.

This is my current approach:

```
ssh -tt my.server -L 8001:localhost:8000 <<'ENDSSH'

trap 'start server as service in normal mode' 2

stop server
start server in debug mode

ENDSSH
```

However, when I hit CTRL C, the ssh connection is terminated and the command inside the trap is not executed.

Complete scripting newbie here. Need help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Normally `ssh` is able to "relay" <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> and cause SIGINT on the remote side, when the following happens:

- `ssh` requests and gets a tty on the remote side,
- `ssh` configures the local tty, so <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> is not special, and reads from it.

In such case <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> will not make the local terminal driver send SIGINT to the foreground process group (i.e. to `ssh`). `ssh` will read `^C` *character* and pass it to the server like any other character. The remote terminal driver will get the character and cause SIGINT *on the server* (or not, depending on its own settings). See [*How is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> sent over SSH?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/723585/108618)

Here you redirect stdin of `ssh`. The tool reads from the here document, not from a tty. Even if the local tty was configured not to send SIGINT, `^C` from <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> you type could never get to the remote side, because `ssh` does not read from the tty at all. If `^C` was literally in the here document then it could trigger SIGINT on the remote side. (Note I don't mean `^` followed by `C`, it has to be the single-byte character [we *denote* `^C`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret_notation), ASCII ETX, 0x03.) Compare tricks in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1735624/432690) where I send <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> by printing the respective characters.

Since your local `ssh` does not read from the tty, it has no reason to reconfigure it in the first place. Your <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> causes SIGINT *locally* and terminates `ssh`. *In general* the remote process (like `start server in debug mode`) may be able to survive this.

If you want <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> you *type* to get to the server, you absolutely want your `ssh` to read from the terminal. This means you *cannot* use a here document.

There are at least two ways:

1. Store the shell code in a script on the remote side, ssh straightforwardly into an interactive shell (where <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> "simply" works as expected) and just run the script.
2. Or pass the shell code as an argument (or arguments) to `ssh`, not via its stdin. This method will not allocate a tty on the remote side automatically, but you need it, so use `-t` (`-tt` will also work).

   Example:

   ```
   ssh -t my.server -L 8001:localhost:8000 '
   trap "start server as service in normal mode" INT
   stop server
   start server in debug mode
   '
   ```

   Note the whole shell code in the example is single-quoted and it looks easy, but if you need actual single-quotes on the remote side then it gets complicated; see [*How can I single-quote or escape the whole command line in Bash conveniently?*](https://superuser.com/q/1531395/432690)

In any of these cases your local `ssh` will use the local terminal in the way that makes <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> get to the remote side and cause SIGINT *there*.

Comment: thanks a lot! works like a charm! I used your second solution with the single quotes since I want the script in my repository.

Comment: Actually the tomcat wrapper already had a trap inside and I could remove the trap completely. The code in now as simple as 'stop server;
start server in debug mode;
start server as service in normal mode;' and just works. :-)